# Stop executing a javascript function when it is called with another parameters

Tags: javascript

I have following scenario

```
x=1;

myFunction(x){
  if(x==1){
      ...
  }
  else{
      ...
  }

}

myFunction(x);

x=2;
myFunction(x);
```

Now what is happening that the function with parameter 1 is overriding function 
with parameter 2 and executing endlessly. But I wanted to stop the exectution of first function when secondly it is called with another parameter.

My real code-

```
width=1000;
onWidthChange(width);

$(window).resize(function(){
    width=$(window).width();
    onWidthChange(width);
});

function onWidthChange(width){

    if(width>660){
        $(window).on("scroll",function(){
            var pos=$(this).scrollTop();

            $img=$(".navbar-brand img")[0];

            if(pos>=674){
                nav.addClass("navbar-fixed");
                $img.src="images/Whole_Logo_custom_1.png";
            }
            else{
                nav.removeClass("navbar-fixed");
                $img.src="images/logo-v1_4_c.jpg";
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Now the problem here is that the function *onWidthChange* is executing with parameter 1000 and rest all calls generated on resize have no effects.

Comment: *"Now what is happening that the function with parameter 1 is overriding function with parameter 2 and executing endlessly"* No, it isn't; not with that code. Maybe with your real code. So show us that, but *minimized appropriately* into a [mcve].

Comment: Where is the definition of `myFunction`? *hint* you did not include it.